# my code for modalpopup is not working

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

actually the code for modalpopup in vwd is not working.
will anyone pls tell me the actual code format for the ajax control modal popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the below two links which shows how to use the modalpopup.

http://programming.top54u.com/post/AJAX-ModalPopup-Control-Extender.aspx

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

The above link lists out the list of properties and its descriptions .